# Unity - save screencapture to android gallery folder

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, path, screen-capture

From a unity app, i'm trying to capture a screenshot, and store it within the gallery.

```
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Application.dataPath + "SomeLevel.png");
```

the application data path points to the APK file itself - how can i redirect it to the gallery ?

Answer (score 0):

try Application.persistentDataPath rather then Application.data path

also view this

https://answers.unity.com/questions/204372/saving-screenshots-to-android-gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin to save image to the gallery. This applies to both Android and iOS. The Android requires the gallery to be refreshed after saving the image. The *NativeGallery* plugin which is free and works for both Android and iOS can be used to do this with the `NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery` function. You can get it [here](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery). This saves you time of having to make your own.

To save the image with the plugin, you have to abandon the `ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot` function and manually take the screenshot yourself with the `ReadPixels` function, convert it to png or jpeg then save the byte array with the `NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery` function.

```
IEnumerator TakeAndSaveScreenshot()
{

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    //Get Image from screen
    screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    screenImage.Apply();
    //Convert to png
    byte[] imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();

    //Save image to gallery
    NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(imageBytes, "AlbumName", "ScreenshotName.png", null);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
StartCoroutine(TakeAndSaveScreenshot());
```